# Traversing path in C#

Tags: c#, .net, path

Why does
`Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"\\folder1\folder2\..\anotherFolder"));`
print `\\folder1\folder2\anotherFolder` and not `\\folder1\anotherFolder`?

While `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"\\folder1\folder2\folder3\..\anotherFolder"));` prints `\\folder1\folder2\anotherFolder` as I would expect it.

It seems as if I can not escape the first two folders of my path. But every folder after the two.

---

Edit:
Actually it is:
`Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFullPath(@"\server\share\..\anotherFolder"));`

Which explains the behaviour.

Comment: With `@` you do not need `\\\`. If you want to use an UNC path, don't call a server folder1.

Comment: _If you want to use an UNC path, don't call a server folder1._

Guess that is part of the miss understanding I had. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a network path the first part (`folder1` in your example) is the server name. The second part `folder2` is the share name. You can use `..` to traverse up an actual folder but not a share.